# Show dialog and start new activity onBackPressed - Android

Tags: android, dialog

how to show a confirmation `dialog` to goto another `activity` on back button? i am getting **`The constructor Intent(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MainActivity>) is undefined`**
error on `new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
                    new    AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Confirm Navigation")
                            .setMessage("are you sure you want to goto main menu?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
```

`this` is not a valid context.